# Two strings compare equal using '=' but fail in 'like' compare

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, string-comparison

`Sql-Server 2008 R2` Collation is `Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AS`.
When I use

```
select 1 where N'⑦' = N'7'
```

it output 1, but when I change the operator to `like`

```
select 1 where N'⑦' like N'7'
```

it wont output anything.

Why is `like` operator act so weird? Did I miss something?

Comment: below link may help you. seems like a known issue https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/703959/search-with-like-not-working-as-expected-with-collation-slovenian-100-ci-as

Comment: Don't see how that connect issue is related (apart from being another issue with `LIKE`)

Comment: `N'⑦' like N'7%'` and `N'7' like N'⑦%'` both return results. Report it on Connect. Doesn't seem like expected behaviour to me.

Comment: it is basically the problem with how the LIKE operator works. Like usually do a character by character comparison

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug. `LIKE` against a pattern without wildcards should always return the same thing that `=` returns.

Others can see this behavior by running the following query:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN N'⑦' COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AS = N'7' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
   CASE WHEN N'⑦' COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AS LIKE N'7' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
-- Y N
```

I see that you [reported it on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/753343/two-strings-compare-equal-using-but-fail-in-like-compare).